# Getting all rows from excel that is not formatted as a table

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Trying to build a flow that would trigger when a new file in a folder is created (using onedrive business for this one). Basically, if I choose *get a row* , it requires my excel files to have a table to get data from it. However, files I receive are not always formatted so I need something that would parse the files regardless of whether or not it is formatted as table. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, use Office Scripts.  You'll need to make sure your licence covers it but most do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Or the only other real alternative is the Microsoft Graph API's ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

They allow you to perform a number of functions, one of which is getting range based data that is not formatted as a table.

Comment: didn't know about Scripts. you live and learn.. thank you @Skin

Comment: No worries, feel free to flag it as the answer if you're satisfied.  If you need help with anything, I suggest opening another question.

Comment: just discovered that it will only work with newer excel files. Some of the files I am working with come through as excel 97-2003

Comment: Oh that's gross, if that's the case then you're going to struggle (I think) with any method.  Can you not convert them to the current version?

Comment: I can manually but the idea is to automate the process. File received -> data extracted -> inserted into sql db. Some customers are using old excel and will not update until it's no longer available

Comment: There are connectors that can help you but it'll likely cost.